# Generate skeleton from depthmap file

Tags: c#, python, kinect, openni, xbox

I have been working on a school project for the last few months, where I have been automatically generating skeleton files from depthmap files, taken by an XBox Kinect. I would like to compare my accuracy with other algorithms, but I am struggling to find algorithms that don't use a physical Kinect device, and instead just a depthmap file. Does anyone know of a software that does this? Links appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not a skeleton, but a bounding box can be generated with [this project](https://github.com/l5shi/Human-Detection-In-Depth-Image). I'm still very much open to suggestions.